# Deploying TypeScript to Azure - Your project file uses a different version of the TypeScript compiler

Tags: azure, typescript, azure-web-app-service

I've been working with TypeScript 1.4 and VS2013 Update 4 on a project which deploys via CD to Windows Azure.

This was working happily up til yesterday, but today I'm getting the following error which seem to relate to the version of TypeScript tools on the Azure build server:

```
 4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(103,5): error : Your project file uses a different version of the TypeScript compiler and tools than is currently installed on this machine.  No compiler was found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\1.4\tsc.exe.  You may be able to fix this problem by changing the <TypeScriptToolsVersion> element in your project file. [d:\a\src\MyProject\MyProject.Web\MyProject.Web.csproj]
 4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(103,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\1.4\tsc.exe" is invalid. [d:\a\src\MyProject\MyProject.Web\MyProject.Web.csproj]
 4>Done Building Project "d:\a\src\MyProject\MyProject.Web\MyProject.Web.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

I've tried removing the `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.4</TypeScriptToolsVersion>` 
Line in my .csproj file and updating it to 1.5 in case the azure servers have updated to the new beta, but this doesn't seem to have helped.

Is anyone else seeing this issue at the moment? I've not changed anything on my project or Azure config since my last successful build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been reported to the VS Online Service Delivery Team and they are working on a fix.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/archive/2015/07/27/type-script-issues-with-visual-studio-online-build-controllers-7-27-investigating.aspx

The above also links to an msdn forum thread describing a few different workarounds in the meantime.